# Installing Nifi on Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: unix, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, apache-nifi

I have created a Google Compute engine and unpacked the Nifi tar file.

The zookeeper setting in the `nifi.properties` file is set to false, the port has been changed to `9090` for `nifi.web.http.port`. I have even created a firewall rule for the compute engine which enables this port.

After starting the NiFi, I can see in the logs that NiFi has started and it shows that it is running through the compute engine's internal IP address.

In my browser, I am trying to access it using the external IP address and the port number above, but I am still not able to bring up the UI. Do I need to change any other settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to set the `nifi.web.http.host` value to the external hostname of the instance so that NiFi is listening to requests there. If you look at the end of the `logs/nifi-app.log` file, you should see a section like the following, listing where NiFi is listening:

```
2019-05-03 20:31:58,632 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer NiFi has started. The UI is available at the following URLs:
2019-05-03 20:31:58,632 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer http://192.168.1.21:8080/nifi
2019-05-03 20:31:58,632 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer http://10.137.0.138:8080/nifi
2019-05-03 20:31:58,632 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer http://127.0.0.1:8080/nifi
2019-05-03 20:31:58,634 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener Successfully initiated communication with Bootstrap
2019-05-03 20:31:58,634 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Controller initialization took 21115087817 nanoseconds (21 seconds).
```

You can use any of the addresses listed there to connect to your NiFi instance. If the external hostname is not listed, you need to ensure you populate it for the property specified above. You may also need to specify a particular network interface for GCE; I have heard of similar issues on AWS in the past.

Comment: I solved it by specifying a network tag to my compute engine instance

Comment: What do you mean network tag? I'm facing this issue as well and can't get the UI to load with my domain name