# Initiating Nifi GUI when installed on Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: user-interface, google-cloud-platform, apache-nifi

I have reviewed this post but it is **not** helping:

[Installing Nifi on Google Cloud Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625322/installing-nifi-on-google-cloud-compute-engine)

Here is what I have already done:

- installed java 11 on ubuntu lts
- installed nifi on ubuntu lts

This is what i have when i start the `nifi.sh` :

```
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
NiFi home: /usr/lib/nifi

Bootstrap Config File: /usr/lib/nifi/conf/bootstrap.conf
```

I have even tried to edit the `nifi.properties` by editing `nifi.web.http.host` and `nifi.web.port`

`nifi.web.host=MY external ip from GCE`

`nifi.web.port=8080`

I have even adjusted the Firewall settings and added port 8080(tcp) any my ip in IPRanges.

**When I try to start the NIFI GUI it just does NOT load.**

Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

As per this [doc](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/getting-started.html#for-linuxmacos-users) can you cross check whether it is installed properly . Seems to be the default port for nifi is 8443.  As you said changed to 8080, make sure that this port is  not running in any other service and also there is no firewall blocking for this port.
open a web browser and navigate to `https://localhost:8443/nifi` or replace the port that you have changed and give it a try.

As per this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625322/installing-nifi-on-google-cloud-compute-engine), cross check whether the logs are listening or not by using `logs/nifi-app.log`. Share the screenshot if you are getting any errors.

Refer to this similar kind of issue :  [link1](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Unable-to-open-NIFI-web-UI/m-p/226373#M188233), [link2](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Unable-to-load-the-WEB-UI-of-NIFI/td-p/229629), [link3](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Unable-to-load-the-WEB-UI-of-NIFI/td-p/229629)